# Collection reverse executing earlier than other code, how to prevent it?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, reverse

Collection reverse executing earlier than other code, how to prevent it?

```
public static void pingpondelete(String str) {
  boolean isTrue = false;

  char arr[] = str.toCharArray();

  ArrayList < Character > chars = new ArrayList < Character > ();

  for (char ch: arr) {
   chars.add(ch);
  }

  int size = chars.size();

  while (size > 1) {
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0 && isTrue == false) {
     chars.remove(chars.get(i));
     size = size - 1;
     isTrue = true;
    } else if (i % 2 != 0 && isTrue == true) {
     chars.remove(chars.get(i));
     size = size - 1;
     isTrue = false;
    }
    Collections.reverse(chars);
   }

   for (char c: chars) {
    System.out.println(c);
   }

  }
}
```

Comment: move it outside of for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move that `Collections.reverse(chars);` call outside of the for loop. Right now it is calling that function everytime the loop runs.

Side note: what is it you are trying to do, I suspect there might be a better, cleaner way.

Comment: I want to delete every other value from the loop then reverse and do it again until the length will be one. Example [1,2,3,4,5] -> [2,4] -> [4,2] ->[2]